# What "unusual" syntax assembly languages are/were there?

Tags: history, assembly

This question may have the apparent form of a question soliciting a "list" answer, but I'm expecting the list to be very short, so please bear with me.

What "unusual" syntax assembly languages are/were there?  My reason for asking this was that the first assembly language programming I did was on the English Electric KDF9, whose weird and wonderful assembly syntax is described below.

That needs some explanation for sure.

Most assembly languages for current handware follow a fairly similar lexical stucture.  The opcode maps to a alpahbetic symbol (occasionally augmented by digits or a couple of other characters, for example period or underscore)., generally suggesting a verb. An instruction has an optional label, followed by the opcode symbol, followed by the operands. The operands may include a handful of symbols which indicate indexing, indirection, address mode, etc.

That is, despite the variation in specifics, the general pattern is like

```
LABEL:  LOAD REG,FOO
        ADD REG,BAR
        STORE REG,FOO
```

So that's the sort of pattern I'm not interested in, for this question. A few weird delimiters added to the above don't count either.

In prestandard days, though, there were sometimes interesting variations.

**Example 1**

[KDF9 Usercode](http://www.findlayw.plus.com/KDF9/The%20Software%20of%20the%20KDF9.pdf), admittedly a fairly impoverished assembly language (no arbitrary user-defined symbols!) had what has been described as 'distributed syntax'.  For example, an indexed load from memory to stack ("nest" in KDF9 terminoolog) is written like

```
V42M7Q;
```

'V42' is the name of some data item (no arbitrary user-defined symbols!), M7 means 'modified by register 7', and Q means that the modifier is to be incremented afterwards.  (Where other machines had 'index registers', KDF9 had 'Q-registers', divided into modifier, counter, and increment parts, uxeful for indexing, base addresses, counting, and array access).  The operation was implicitly a fetch; store would be indicated by '='.

Adding two numbers would thus look like

```
V42;  V43; +;  =V42;  (FOO = FOO + BAR);
```

This is "fetch V42 to stack; fetch V43 to stack; add top 2 stack words and leave sum on stack; pop stack and store in V42".  The addition operation is indicated by '+' and not by, say, 'ADD'.  It's a zero-address machine so the operands are implciit. The parenthetical clause is a comment.  And newlines have no significance - this was fairly common in papertape cultures.

There were some data-manipulation instructions that did use 'words' for them, when there was no reasonably mnemonic symbol in the Flexowriter repertoire.  For example, `DUP;` duplicated the top-of-stack value (i.e., pushed another copy on the stack).

**Example 2**

[Manchester University's MU5](https://ethw.org/The_University_of_Manchester_MU5_Computer_System) also had an interesting syntax. The addition example would be written as

```
      ACC = FOO
      ACC + BAR
      ACC => FOO
```

ACC is the name of a machine register, obviously the accumulator. The rest of the symbols should be self-explanatory.

(Bio note: I have programmed on the KDF9. I never met the MU5, though it was discussed in undergrad courses as an exciting example of a machine designed for higher-level languages, that the guys over in Manchester were inventing.  I know there's at least one MU5 programmer in this forum).

**Not an example**

I'm excluding things like Turing's programming system at Manchester, since that just consisted in typing whatever teleprinter symbol made up the next 5 bits of the instruction stream.

---

So: was that the extent of the scenic detour off the highway to dull standardization, or are there other interesting examples?

Clarification: for this question, the assembly language should have been intended in principle for human programmers to use to write programs. Languages only intended for communication between programs, say as communication between different stages of a programming system, are excluded.
Also, I'm only interested in actual code. No pseudo-ops, no directives, no macro definitions or calls, and not data declarations either.

Comment: Most Forth implementations had a reverse polish assembler.

Comment: Not at all retro, but Analog Devices' Blackfin CPUs use a very high-level-looking assembly language: `R0 = R1 + R2` for example.

Comment: In your question, do you mean "official" assembly languages only or, possibly, variations of the more traditional assembly languages too? The reason I am asking is that I know, for example, an "alternative" assembly for Z80, which feels quite relevant for what you asked, but is, of course, not Z80 assembly as everyone knows it.

Comment: Current count for this "not a list" answer is already up to 7. Highest voted answer should probably be converted to a Community Wiki.

Comment: Do intermediate assembler languages like ocode, acode, pcode and bytecode count?  They're all reverse polish.

Comment: @BrianH re list count.  Indeed. There are more weird syntaxes in heaven and earth than are dreamt of in my philosophy!  I should get out more.

Comment: @cup - I was thinking of languages used by humans, so no, I should clarify.

Comment: Also see [What is the origin of different styles of assembly language mnemonics?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3195/4025)

Comment: How high level are you willing to consider as 'assembly' language? There are at least a few hardware/VHDL implementations of runtime VM's out there (Jazelle on ARM for example, and there have been research projects to do soft-core implementations of BEAM and the CIL runtime in hardware). Depending on how you consider those, that expands the list quite significantly.

Comment: There were easily 100 different assembly languages over the years, not counting one-off inventions by individual programmers who needed to work around the limitations of other tools.  (I myself invented a couple.)  Some used clearly understandable mnemonics, while others were pure gibberish and required you to have a cheat sheet on hand to read/write, even if you were familiar with the language.  Some had rigid formatting rules, while others would let you string things out anyway you wanted.

Comment: This has been a thoroughly interesting discussion, but I have to pick one answer to fit the SE "Q & A" format. I'm going with the answer that mentioned the CDC 6600 since that seems the weirdest.

Comment: KDF9 doesn't look that strange: it's a straightforward "reverse Polish notation" of the sort you'd expect to find on a stack machine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Example 1

The PDP-8 had only 8 kinds of instructions, but one of them was "microcoded" operate command: Different bits in this command would turn on different operations, which could be combined. Here's a list of the first group of such commands:

```
7000 NOP   no operation
7001 IAC   increment acc
7002 BSW   byte swap (-> rotate twice)
7004 RAL   rotate acc and link left one
7006 RTL   rotate acc and link left two
7010 RAR   rotate acc and link right one
7012 RTR   rotate acc and link right two
7020 CML   complement link
7040 CMA   complement acc
7100 CLL   clear link
7200 CLA   clear acc
```

So if you wanted to clear the accumulator and then increment it, effectively loading the constant 1 into the accumolator, you could combine the opcodes:

```
CLA IAC
```

and the assembler would OR the corresponding bit patterns to give you `7201` as the octal opcode.

The same worked for all other combinations (but not all of them would do something useful).

### Example 2

There are CPUs that use a subset of Forth as their assembly language, and Forth is of course quite different from the "standard" assmbler syntax you describe in the question.

One relatively modern example is an FPGA implementation called [J1 Forth CPU](https://www.excamera.com/sphinx/fpga-j1.html). [Here](https://www.excamera.com/files/j1demo/docforth/basewords.fs.html) you can see how the Forth operations are defined in terms of this "machine language".

### Example 3

The CDC 6000 series had a variation of the "standard" assembly syntax where you could mix in an arithmetic symbol on the right hand side, making it more look like a mathematical formula. Also, the result register was part of the operand mnemonic. So

```
BX1   X2 * X3
```

would calculate the logical product ("AND") of registers X2 and X3 and store it in register X1, while

```
BX1  -X2 + X3
```

would complement register X2, and then form the logical sum ("OR") with register X3 and store it in register X1. Both of these had a single opcode each.

Similarly,

```
FX1   X2 + X3
```

would calculate the floating point sum of X2 and X3, and store it in X1.

### Example 4

The IAS family (ENIAC etc.) also had an assembler notation that looked more mathematical. Note that no actual assembler as a program existed, these were translated by hand into opcodes. An example from [this site](http://www.cs.colby.edu/djskrien/IASSim/):

```
; adds up the values n+...+3+2+1(+0) in a loop and stores
; the sum in memory at the location labeled "sum"

loop:   S(x)->Ac+  n    ;load n into AC
        Cc->S(x)   pos  ;if AC >= 0, jump to pos
        halt            ;otherwise done
        .empty          ;a 20-bit 0
pos:    S(x)->Ah+  sum  ;add n to the sum
        At->S(x)   sum  ;put total back at sum
        S(x)->Ac+  n    ;load n into AC
        S(x)->Ah-  one  ;decrement n
        At->S(x)   n    ;store decremented n
        Cu->S(x)   loop ;go back and do it again   

n:     .data 5  ;will loop 6 times total
one:   .data 1  ;constant for decrementing n
sum:   .data 0  ;where the running/final total is kept
```

### Possible other examples

I guess there's more, in particular for very early computers, assembler notation was all over the place. The reason for that is that the "standard" assembler notation makes it easy for an actual assembler program to do the translation. With translations done by hand, as in the above example, there is no pressure to make the notation easy to parse by a program.

Comment: Example 1 sounds quite similar to the HP 1000 series CPU. It's assembly language contained two "groups" called "alter / skip" and "shift / rotate", in which instructions could be combined by ORing them.

Comment: I was going to mention Forth CPUs, the example I was thinking of was the GreenArrays GA144 - which will seem familiar to those who have played TIS-100 :) .  Example MD5 implementation on a GA144 : http://www.greenarraychips.com/home/documents/greg/AN001-141023-MD5.pdf

Comment: Maybe SHARC DSPs assembly, using infix notation and showing parallel execution of load/store, ALU...

Comment: For the CDC 6000 example, is ```BX1 X2 * X3``` still a single machine instruction?

Comment: @another-dave Yes, it's a single instruction, like the other examples.

Comment: `RAR` appears twice with different opcodes. Typo?

Comment: OK, the CDC 6000 assembler (COMPASS) is authentically weird. In ```BX1 X2 * X3```, there are multiple opcodes with the same ```BX1``` mnemonic, the 1 is actual an operand designator, and the ```*``` is part of the opcode. Right?

Comment: @another-dave Right. And not only is the `1` an operand designator, you can also have commands like `SA1 A2 + B3` and `SB1 A2 + B3` where `A1` means register A1, and `B1` register B1, just as `X1` means register X1 in `BX1`; and `S` means "set to".

Comment: The Harris RTX2000 (real time processor as it was called as I recall) was designed to directly implement `FORTH`. I remember going to a Harris seminar in the mid - late 80s where it was introduced. Interesting page at https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/stack_computers/sec4_5.html

Comment: What determines the order of the combined operations in PDP-8? I.e. why `7201` is `CLA IAC` and not `IAC CLA`?

Comment: @Zeus You can *write* them in any order in assembly. The order of "execution" is always the same, and determined by the way the functional blocks are arranged in the hardware. So you can both write `CLA IAC` and `IAC CLA`, but the accumulator always gets cleared first, because that's just a pulldown/and gate where the signal exits the "old" accumulator.

Comment: If I recall correctly, PAL-8 syntax is just to 'or' together expressions it finds on the same line.

Comment: @another-dave Yes.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that the PDP-8 counts as weird. It's fairly conventional syntax except for the existence of the OPR instructions.  But the CDC 6600's total confusion of operand and opcode makes up for it - now that **is** weird!

Answer (score 30):

This is a *[frame challenge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6843/2947)* answer.

The [Burroughs Large Systems B5000](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Burroughs_large_systems#B5000) was specifically designed for being able to run programs in high-level languages (meaning COBOL, ALGOL, FORTRAN), multiprocessing, virtual memory. It had tagged memory, and builtin concurrency and multiprocessing.

The feature relevant to this particular question, is rather *lack of* a feature: the B5000 doesn't *have* an assembly language. Its "lowest" system programming language is [Executive Systems Problem Oriented Language (ESPOL)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Systems_Problem_Oriented_Language), an extension of ALGOL 60.

ESPOL, however, *does* have direct equivalents for all low-level instructions.

The B5000 was a big influence on Alan Kay both in the design of OO in general and the design of the Smalltalk VM. It was also reportedly an influence on the Pascal P-Code system (which was also an influence on the Smalltalk VM). The Smalltalk VM and P-Code, in turn, were an influence on the JVM. So, in the biological sense of "success" (spreading your genes), it is one of the most successful hardware architectures in the history of computing.

Comment: And of course the KDF9 mentioned in the question was a big influence on the Burroughs B5000, so it's not that surprising you also get a similar syntax.

Comment: I claim that a non-existent language doesn't have unusual syntax. I can think of lots of languages that don't exist, and they all have the exact same written form :-)

Comment: @dirkt Are you sure? If Wikipedia is to be believed (which, I know, is not always the case), the B5000 actually preceded the KDF9 by about three years.

Comment: @another-dave: As I wrote in the preface, this is a *frame challenge* answer. I would argue that the language on the B5000 which plays the role that assembly languages play on almost all other architectures, has an unusual syntax for an assembly language. Now, the reason for that is, of course, that it *isn't* an assembly language, it is a high-level language in the ALGOL family which also has different *semantics*, but nevertheless, it is *used* in domains where you would otherwise use assembly language, and it is used by engineers who would otherwise use assembly language.

Comment: @another-dave This would lead to the meta question: What *is* an assembly language? Does a Forth CPU that is programmed in a subset of Forth have an assembly language? Does that make (that subset of) Forth an assembly language?

Comment: @MichaelGraf My notes for the Burrough have a quote by Gary Kildall that says this series is an "offshoot of the English Electric KDF-9". I have not writting down the source of the quote, and I cannot find it quickly. I also didn't verify it. So it might be that Gary Kildall was mistaken, that the quote is wrong, or that the development of the B5000 series actually was inspired by the development of the KDF9, no matter which was released earlier - I don't know, and I didn't check. But they do look similar enough, if you look at it, so there's definitely an influence, in whatever direction.

Comment: I think that both KDF9 and B5000 are products of their time, rather than influencing each other. The fine details are also quite different. The Burroughs machine has "all memory" stack structures with a couple of fast registers for the top; the KDF9 has a 16-deep 'accumulator' stack for expression eval and a 16-deep return-address stack, neither of which is suitable for (say) Algol procedure activation records.

Comment: Later Burroughs machines (6500?) added hardware for concepts implemented in software for the KDF9 Whetstone Algol compiler (Randell & Russell) - like the display structure for uplevel references, so there was influence that way.

Comment: @MichaelGraf (meta q) - let's not get too deep into the wormhole :-)  For this question I say there's a real machine, generally one operation in a program in the language is one operation in the machine (not prejudging the mnemonic-to-opcode issue), and for this question it's intended for human programmers. For the Forth question, I would regard that as 2 similar but distinct languages.

Comment: Do you have a source for your last para regarding the VMs?

Comment: I feel like this answer is somehow insane. It ran compiled code. The resulting binaries can be broken down into individual machine instructions, and rendered for viewing by humans, and then modified, and the new binary executed. Now what do we call the readable mnemonics for machine instructions hmmm?

Comment: How was the binary modified? How was the modified form prepared for execution?  I'm inclined to take Burroughs documentation at its word that there was no assembler.

Comment: @another-dave: I think it means they didn't ship an assembler. Some old mainframes had the memory security in the compiler, and if you could hand-craft an binary and somehow set it up to run you could bypass the security.

Comment: I think the MCP required you to bless any compiler, but that's not related to whether there was an assembler (you could install a crooked compiler). I am pretty sure there was no assembler -- first versions of the "systems Algol" compiler were hand-compiled to machine code -- and thereafter you're off to the races in the traditional compiler-bootstrapping manner.

Answer (score 17):

*[**Preface**: This question is not only quite broad, but as well rather opinion bases. After all, what is 'unusual' depends a lot on personal experience and preference. To me for example GNU assembler's inversion of target and source is quite unusual.*

*Having said that, I feel the question gives a great chance to create some overview]*

---

As I understand it, the question is about how an Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) is represented in its (native) assembler, and what variations exist. It's important to keep in mind that this is strongly influenced by the way an ISA is viewed (*1)

### Basic Schools

There are several *basic* schools of ISA representation in Assembler:

(I tried to use as modern examples as possible to ease reading)

1. One Opcode one Mnemonic

   Each and every binary opcode gets its own mnemonic. A typical example would be the Datapoint 2200 or Intel's 8008. Here each opcode gets its own name:

- `LAB` - **L**oad register **A** with the content of register **B**
- `LAM` - **L**oad register **A** with the memory content addressed by the **M**emory pointer (HL)
- `LA #` - **L**oad register **A** with the constant `#` given as parameter

  Assemblers of this kind can be written very fast as all they have to follow is a one-on-one replacement of the mnemonic to an opcode and optionally turning a simple, usually numeric, value into a byte/word sized parameter. They are extremely close to the binary ISA representation. These tend to be quite small and are often the first stage to get a system running. The 6502 and the first cross-assembler running on a timeshare system are good examples.

2. One Mnemonic many opcodes

   Here each mnemonic describes a function; the opcode used is to be derived from the parameter given. The most radical or clean, as one prefers, of the classic 8-bit age might be the Z80. Here all 161 possible encodings for data transfer between registers and register and memory are summarized in one mnemonic `LD`.

   This clearly eases learning as a new programmer can focus more on generic function used than specific encoding. Of course it comes with a more complex assembler structure, as now parameters must be scanned before deciding on the opcode to be generated - and its parameter - accordingly. It may end up with source constructions in need of additional specifiers to pick the right opcode - Motorola's 68000 `.b`/`.w`/`.l` postfix notation, for example. Or the unique (*2) address syntax on a 6502.
3. Encoding like Structure

   While this may sound like a sub section to #1, it's not much about giving a distinct encoding to each instruction, but about the mnemonic *being* the instruction - effectively reducing the assembler even more. An example would be the IBM TPM (Tape Processing Machine) and its 701 follow-up, where the opcodes were directly related to 5-bit TTY encoding. Like `A` for Add, `W` for Write - of course, it did work out way less easy to remember for many other instructions :)
4. Synthetic Mnemonics

   Here no fixed opcodes are given, but an operation is synthesized from a set of symbols. It works somewhat like qualifiers, except that none of the elements are a base opcode. Operation is usually VLIW-like. The most prominent example here is maybe the [Zuse Z22](/q/9673).
5. Single Parameter

   These syntaxes try to limit parameters to a single one, even if the abstract logic of the instruction is about two independent ones. This is much like the #1 attempt for opcodes. The 6502/6800 make good examples by encoding one parameter into the instruction:

   - `LDA` - **L**oa**d** register **A**
   - `LDY` - **L**oa**d** register **Y**
   - `LDAB`- **L**oa**d** **A**ccumulator **B**
6. Multiple Parameters

   Others allow for two or more distinct parameters. While limited two-address ISAs can get around with byzantine mnemonic constructions (such as 6800's `LDAA`), full two-address must go that way.

   This is much related to the move from a type #1 mnemonic structure to a type #2. And like it, an assembler handling such source statements will need to be more complex in its decision tree - for example decoding different addressing modes and selecting the opcode accordingly.
7. Embedded Parameter

   These syntaxes do not spread out parameters over separate elements (words) but concatenate them into the instruction. While this is to some degree true for #5 syntax, it goes beyond, as no spaces or delimiters are used at all. 'Freiburger' Code for the Z22 for example goes that way:

   - `T5000T` is a pseudo op working much like `ORG` in other assemblers, setting Drum location 5000 as next target.
   - `CB3000` instruction to load a word from address 3000
8. Parameter Order or Left to Right vs. Right to Left?

   Should parameters be given as *source* first or *destination* first? This is as much a source of holy wars (*3) as it is about history. Early (Load/Store) architectures often encoded one parameter as part of the instruction, inherently using both ways:

   - The 6502's LDA/X/Y: the register mentioned in the mnemonic would be the first parameter, so making it *destination, source*, while
   - its STA/X/Y turns it into *source, destination.*
   - Transfers (Txx) also use *source, destination.*

   Since most instructions, except stores, use the destination-first notation, it does seem more natural when assemblers evolved/had to evolve from single to multiple parameter. Then again, some two-address machines' ISAs were structured as source,destination from the very first iteration on.

   Of course, with more than two parameters, it gets even more arbitrary.

### Real Assemblers:

While some assemblers are direct implementations of one of these schools (and mentioned above), many are combinations. Examples may be:

- 8080 and 6800/6502 are mixtures of #1 and #2.

  - While Intel did unify some instructions on the move from 8008 to 8080, like turning all loads between registers into a single `MOV` mnemonic, it kept a separate mnemonic all other data transfers.
  - 6800/6502 did unify most instructions of the same function into a single mnemonic and have the parameter addressing decide which encoding, but at the same time all register to register transfers got their own mnemonic (`TAX`, `TXA`, ...)
- 'Freiburger Code' might be something in between assembler, loader and script processor. Its basic syntax is meant to create the various bit of the instruction, but it can also execute an instruction *while* assembling/loading if an `E` is appended. Using an `E` as prefix in turn can load any instruction from memory and execute it (`E4010` -> execute instruction at memory location 4010). There are several other such pseudo-instructions and instruction modifiers as well - effectively blurring borders between assembler source, compiler script, command script and application.

---

*1  For example a /360 is usually seen as a single opcode to mnemonic relation (#1), as that's the way it is used in all documentation. But no-one stops us from seeing the opcodes as structured in a 2+6 fashion with the top two bits holding the addressing modes (for most instructions).

*2 - But not always simple/intuitive.

*3 - Quite much like the war between using 'Move' vs. 'Load/Store'. While I, as a /360 guy, would like to see both, I've experienced quite fierce discussions favouring either.

Comment: The gas syntax is also unusual and much less readable to me (esp. the memory dereference syntax). They made things even far worse by making everything harder to look up in the CPU manual

Comment: @phuclv: GAS was just being compatible with an existing Unix assembler for some existing 386 Unix at the time.  That made sense at the time.  It's really unfortunate that whoever those clowns were picked some craptastic syntax different from the Intel manuals, influenced by PDP11.  [What was the original reason for the design of AT&T assembly syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42244028)  (And they even got the operands reversed vs. the normal AT&T convention for some x87 non-commutative instructions.)  So blame them, not GNU; At least most tools can use `.intel_syntax noprefix` these days

Comment: re: gas syntax - as a non-x86-assembly programmer who occasionally needed to read it, I found the Intel syntax to be incoherent.  I think it's a matter of what you're used to.

Comment: @PeterCordes The Gnu Assembler was written originally for VAX/11 which used a source first format. Also Stallman started writing Gnu on a 68000 system, again a source first format. It was also expected to be used mainly as a backend for gcc generated output, not for humans to write in.

Comment: @JeremyP: I guess that would explain why GAS picked the (pre-existing I think) source-first AT&T syntax for x86, then.  GAS for ARM, MIPS, and plenty of other ISAs is destination-first, using the only syntax that ever existed for those platforms.  (\@another-dave: if you want incomprehensible, PowerPC does it for me.  So much functionality packed into each instruction, multiple immediate fields for (very nice) insns like `rlwinm`, but hard-to-read choices for mnemonics, numbering bits IBM-style from the top of the register, and there's even an `eieio` mnemonic.)

Answer (score 14):

[SHARC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/GettingStartedwithSharcProcessors.pdf) and [Blackfin](https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/processor-manuals/Blackfin_pgr_rev2.2.pdf) architectures processors are said to have *"rich algebraic assembly language syntax"* and are unsual in their own way. The [syntax](https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/software-manuals/50_asm_mn_rev_3.4.pdf) is somewhat C-like

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_BUFFER3
.VAR buffer3[ 0x100];
#endif

outer:
[I1] = R0;
R1 = 0X1234;

LSETUP (begin_loop, end_loop) LC0 = P1;
begin_loop:
        R1 *= R2;
        R2 = [I0++];
end_loop:
         R0= R0 + R1 (NS) || R1 = [P0++] || NOP
R0 = R0 + R1
JUMP outer;

R0 = DLAB | EPS (z);
cc = BITSET (R0, BITPOS(DLAB));
```

The TigerSHARC variant is a VLIW architecture and has similar highly readable instructions:

```
start:
XR0 = CB [J3 += 1];;
if NLC0E, jump start;;
```

Comment: TI TMS320 series also often have algebraic syntax

Answer (score 12):

It would be remiss if we're talking about assembler syntax to leave out the clever assemblers for Forth.

Clever in that writing assemblers for Forth is quite straightforward and historically requires very little code.

Forth assemblers are noted for their prefix syntax and they're idiomatic use of higher level branching and looping constructs in contrast to typical assembly leveraging comparisons, branch instructions, jumping and looping. Forth assemblers tend to not rely on things like labels. (They exist, they're simply not common in use.)

Forth assembly is also typically done in small chunks.

```
CODE (FIND)   (S here alf -- cfa flag | here false )
  DX POP   DX DX OR  0= IF   AX AX SUB   1PUSH   THEN            
  BEGIN   DX BX MOV   BX INC   BX INC                            
    DI POP  ( here )  DI PUSH   0 [BX] AL MOV                    
    0 [DI] AL XOR   63 # AL AND   0=                             
    IF  BEGIN  BX INC   DI INC   0 [BX] AL MOV                   
          0 [DI] AL XOR   0<> UNTIL   127 # AL AND   0=          
        IF   DI POP   BX INC   BX PUSH   DX BX MOV               
             BX INC   BX INC  0 [BX] AL MOV   64 # AL AND   0<>  
          IF   1 # AX MOV   ELSE   -1 # AX MOV   THEN   1PUSH    
    THEN  THEN   DX BX MOV  0 [BX] DX MOV                        
  DX DX OR   0=  UNTIL   AX AX SUB   1PUSH   END-CODE
```

Commonly found is Forth meta-compilers that build Forth from Forth, the `FIND` routine is often one of the largest assembly routines in the system. But it shows off the assembler handily. Above is the `(FIND)` primitive in 8086 from F83.

This shows off the prefix format `DX POP` vs conventionally `POP DX`. The `0 [BX] AL MOV` is normally `MOV AL, [BX+0]`. Finally, `63 # AL AND` is `AND AL, #63`.

It also shows the use of the `0= IF ... THEN` block. The 0= is testing the Zero flag, if true, it executes the block delimited by the `IF` and `THEN`. No labels here. Similarly, the `BEGIN ... UNTIL` syntax. It also shows simple macros like `1PUSH`.

Finally it represents the nature of a bunch of assembly code arranged to fit on a single 1K byte, 64x16 screen of Forth source code.

Comment: There are also Forth CPU for which the instruction set is simply a binary encoded version of Forth assembly. These are typically implemented as a subset of Forth and more complex instructions like the FIND above will be implemented as libraries

Answer (score 8):

An honourable mention goes to [Programma 101](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olivetti_Programma_101), arguably the first desktop computer. The "programming" was done essentially in an "assembler" corresponding to keystrokes, looking like this (taken from [here](http://www.curtamania.com/curta/database/brand/olivetti/Olivetti%20Programma%20101/index.html)):

```
A V
S
B M↑
B ← M
A / A↑
D / A↓
```

This style has been generally carried on by other programming calculators, though later they started to include a general purpose CPU (with its own, hidden from the user, machine code).

Comment: Oh, I even used one of those!  How could I have forgotten it?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not 100% sure whether this answer qualifies, as the assembler it relates to is still available and updated for at least relatively modern architectures, but it does originally go baack to the 80s and supported 16-bit 8086 compatible CPUs, so perhaps it's appropriate:

[Terse](http://www.terse.com/) is an x86 assembler with a rather unique syntax, designed to resemble high level languages.  An example from the web site is this code:

```
eax = ebx; bx + dog; cat - 14; cx & 0Fh; dx - 123?
```

Which is equivalent to the following traditional 8086 instruction sequence:

```
Mov eax,ebx
Add bx,dog
Sub cat,14
And cx,0Fh
Cmp dx,123
```

The language supports chaining multiple operations that use the same destination register in a single statement, and also higher level concepts like loops, if statements with blocks, and so on.

Answer (score 7):

This thread would not be complete without a reference to [The Story of Mel](http://www.catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html). According to the story, this was a Royal McBee RPC-4000, and its assembler was unique because

```
The new computer had a one-plus-one
addressing scheme,
in which each machine instruction,
in addition to the operation code
and the address of the needed operand,
had a second address that indicated where, on the revolving drum,
the next instruction was located.

In modern parlance,
every single instruction was followed by a GO TO!
```

Comment: The assembler had it because the machine did it like that - no program **counter**, but each instruction specified its successor. That seems to have been common on machines where primary memory was rotating (either magnetic drum or ultrasonic storage).  See [Optimum Programming on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimum_programming), or the [IBM 650 (page 10, instruction format)](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/650/22-6060-2_650_OperMan.pdf) for a specific example. Eventually there were [assemblers](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/650/32-7646-1_SOAPII.pdf) that did that for you.

Comment: @another-dave Sure, and that's basically true of all assemblers - they're really just a mnemonic layer on top of the hardware features.  The structure of the processor's memory, whether that's rotating or RAM-based, Von Neumann or Harvard, and any registers, is always reflected in the assembler mnemonics and how they are fed input and output values.

Comment: But my point for this topic is that the 1+1 address format does not make it syntactically strange.

Answer (score 4):

I used an assembler that did this:

```
  ;...
  call #function
  ;...

function:
  add  v_spc, #1
  ;...
function_ret:
  ret
```

Seems pretty pedestrian until you take note of what happens. Trying to compile this

```
  ;...
  call #function
  ;...

function:
  add  v_spc, #1
  ;...
  ret
```

(missing `function_ret`) yielded an error message at the site of the `call` operation. `function` could still be compiled and jumped to, but calling it was an error. The disassembly revealed the truth.

```
  ;...
  jmpret  L15, #L13
  ;...

L13:
  add L16, #1
  ;...
L15:
  jmpret nw 0, #0
```

The processor is stackless, and the assembler is generating the necessary stuff for function calls to work on the processor.

Comment: IIRC that's similar to how the Parallax Propeller does subroutine calls.

Comment: @AlexHajnal: This is the Parallax Propeller processor.

Comment: LOL.  That would explain the similarity!

Answer (score 3):

The UNIVAC I had an assembly language that was mostly single-letter opcodes.  Here is the "Code Card" developed by [Grace Hopper](http://edan.si.edu/slideshow/viewer/?eadrefid=NMAH.AC.0324_ref300):

[image: UNIVAC I Code Card]

Answer (score 2):

Control Data had the only reasonable syntax I’ve ever seen in the COMPASS assembler for CDC 60 bit computers. Most instructions were one letter for the type of instruction, followed by the destination register, followed by any expression that would fit into one instruction. For example:

```
SA4 A5+B7 - Set register A4 to sum of A5 and B7
IX2 X3-X4 - Integer expression, X2 = X3 -X4
IX2 X3/X4 - Integer expression, X2 = X3 divided by X4.
```

So no separate add/subtract/multiply/divide instructions in the assembly language.

Answer (score 1):

SDS/Xerox Meta-Symbol was essentially a list processing language designed to generate machine code through side effects.

https://www.livingcomputers.org/UI/UserDocs/CP-V/4_MetaSymbol_Assembler_Language_Reference.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a "on the way to assembler" answer.

The FA-5 "Automatic coding system" for BESK doesn't have mnemonics for instructions, those are just notated in normal octal. But, it allows symbolic addressing, computed at "assembly time". The assembled program was printed out, with symbolic addresses replaced by real addresses. It was also (if short enough) stored in RAM, and could be punched to tape, for later loading.

Answer (score -1):

Some people call the (original K&R) C programming language an assembly language for PDP-11's.

Comment: They do, but they're wrong, at least on the basis of ++ and --, according to [Dennis Ritchie](http://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html). I'm inclined to consider him as authoritative.  :-).

Comment: @another-dave The line between Assembler and HLL gets blurry anyway as soon as assemblers offer more than a linear mnemonic/opcode and label/address mapping.